# Ссылки относительно корня сайта php

Tags: php, файлы

```
$root =  $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];

$array = [
  'title' => ['Libertines', $root . '/site/root/rock/index.php', 1],
  'title1' => ['Britnie', $root . '/site/root/pop/index.php', 3],
  'title2' => ['Marley', $root . '/site/root/reaggie/index.php', 4],
  'title3' => ['Wu-tang', $root . '/site/root/rap/index.php', 2],
]; 


function Menu($array) { 
   foreach ($array as $titles) { 
   echo '<a href="'.$titles[1].'">'.$titles[0].'</a>' . "<br>";};
};
```

Ребят, привет. Работаю с этим массивом и возник следующий вопрос. Я хочу сделать так, чтобы ссылки выводились не через относительные, а через корень. Но при выводе ссылок, они почему то становятся не кликабельными т.е. при нажатии перехода на нужную страницу не происходит.

Объясните в чем причина и как ее решить?

Comment: Cсылки должны быть относительно корня сайта. Предоставьте html вывод.

Comment: Не следует путать [корень файловой системы и корень сайта](http://phpfaq.ru/newbie/paths)

Comment: Нажмите правой кнопкой мыши на ссылку и выберите "посмотреть код" и посмотрите корректен ли код ссылки?

Comment: Если кто-то из присутствующих специалистов не в курсе, что лежит в переменной $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'], то я могу подсказать: код в ссылках некорректный.

Comment: @Ипатьев может у него в корне лежит папка `site/root` :D

Answer (score 0):

Значение `DOCUMENT_ROOT` выводит не ссылку на корень сайта в сети Интернет, а адрес в файловой системе сервера. Вы можете попробовать воспользоваться значением из `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` , но рекомендую для этих целей воспользоваться конфигом (ну или просто константа в начале алгоритма), где будет явно указан единственный верный адрес корня с доменом, протоколом и остальной частью. Ваш сайт может быть доступен одновременно с нескольких доменов. Средства PHP не смогут достоверно выяснить верный путь.

Comment: Не нужно никаких конфигов и $_SERVER. Корень сайта всегда один и тот же